# Performance of mysql equi-join observed in HDD and SSD

Tags: mysql, performance, join, hardware, ssd

I experimented performance of queries having equi-joins. I have simplified version of EXPLAINs of the queries.

**Mysql version :** 5.7.18

**Engine :** Innodb

**Cache state :** Mysql restarted before experiment so no buffer pool cache. Since, physical machine is restarted before every experiment there won't be OS cache.

**Note :** Primary key is nothing but an increasing INT.

**CPUs:** SSD machine is a Mac machine with 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7.
      HDD machine is a Mac machine with 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7

**Case 1:**

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     |  ref             | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------+--------+----------+----+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |  const,const     | 190864 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |  c.id.           |      1 |    10.00 | Using where |
```

**Case 2:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+-------
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows   |Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 771     | const,const                 | 190864 |Using index 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 775     | const,const,c.id            |      1 |Using index 
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+--------+
```

I both cases it can be noted that:

- the first table having 190864 rows ready to be joined to second table
- the second table is about to join in 'eq_ref' order.

**Interpretation:**
 Each row from first table is going to find its pair in second table. Since there are 100k rows in first table , there will be 100k i/o to disk in random fashion (i.e., simply random i/o correct me if I were wrong). I have run this experiment with HDD and SSD.

**Results** (time taken):

**Case 1 : 3.409s (SSD) and 26.651s (HDD)**

**Case 2 : 0.248s (SSD) and 1.364s (HDD)**

It can be seen that there is a huge difference in performance. Is this because of that SSD are better at random I/Os? or simply SSDs are better at I/O itself?

Comment: 1 lakh... will edit the question if it is misleading

Comment: (Another common Indian term: 1 Crore = 10M)

Comment: for not add new answer - difference very reasonable (already mentioned by @RickJames. SSD (even old SATA ssd) - faster always, but much better for random read.

Answer (score 1):

I am excited to hear reliable comparisons between HDD and SSD, but first...

Here are some of the variables you have not accounted for.  (Or maybe you did, but failed to state.)

- InnoDB?
- One says "Using index", meaning that the processing happened only in the index's BTree ("Covering" index); the other apparently had to bounce between the secondary index and the data.  This could make a significant difference.
- Table sizes?
- Was the cache (buffer_pool) cold?  Please restart mysqld before each test.
- Same CPU, since you want to focus on the I/O, not the CPU time.
- If it was the same server, which drive was `c` on?
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- there could be subtle issues.
- MySQL version.
- Are the indexes aligned with the data?  For example:  `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `TIMESTAMP` might be virtually in lock-step.  But UUID is very random.

**8x and 5.5x seem to be reasonable.**

Comment: I have updated the question as per you guidance, please check

Comment: both case 1 and case 2 were tested on both HDD and SSD

Comment: @DineshKumar - OK, I will accept that 8 and 5.5 are realistic.  (My other questions were aimed at determining why those ratios are not the same.  However, at some level, this is not important.)

Comment: I want to make sure whether these type of queries as described in case1 will have random i/o especially when rows from first table were equi-referred to second table.

Comment: do you want any further info from my side?

Comment: @DineshKumar - buffer_pool_size and table size (`SHOW TABLE STATUS`) -- The issue is that the blocks may be bumped out of cache and reloaded.  I am currently _guessing_ that the tables add up to much less than a GB and the buffer_pool is much more than a GB; hence no reloading is happening.

Comment: @DineshKumar - On the other hand, if the second table in the JOIN can't be kept in cache, then timestamp vs UUID _may_ make a big difference.

Comment: buffer pool is of 4G and my tables were small enough to be fit into 4G